# Power Query - How to add a Conditional Column based on Variables

Tags: variables, group-by, powerbi, powerquery, m

I have the following problem and I'm looking for solutions in Power Query i.e. not in DAX. This is my starting point:

**Table Name**: Reference Register

| Credit Number | Currency | Credit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | USD | 1,000,000 |
| ABC123 | EUR | 2,000,000 |
| ABC123 | GBP | 3,000,000 |
| OPQ654 | USD | 3,500,000 |
| OPQ654 | EUR | 4,000,000 |
| OPQ654 | GBP | 5,000,000 |
| XYZ555 | USD | 10,000,000 |
| XYZ555 | EUR | 11,000,000 |
| XYZ555 | GBP | 13,000,000 |
| JKL900 | USD | 20,000,000 |
| JKL900 | EUR | 19,000,000 |
| JKL900 | GBP | 16,000,000 |

I want to add an new column which labels each row with either a "Pass" or Fail", as per the following conditions:

For every Credit Number,

if the Credit with Currency USD is null, then all entries for the same Credit Number should get a "Fail"

else if Credit with Currency USD is > null && the Credit with Currency USD is **greater** than the Credit with Currency EUR, then *all entries for the same Credit Number* should get a "Pass"

else if Credit with Currency USD is > null && the Credit with Currency USD is **smaller** than the Credit with Currency EUR, then *all entries for the same Credit Number* should get a "Fail"

else, all entries for the same Credit Number should get a "Pass"

I tried pretty much the above with the various if/else statements, but because I need to look up on a Credit Number Level i.e. it can be multiple rows to look over, I got stuck as I don't know how to best use variables (?), the group by function (?) or any other approach.

For the sample, the expected outcome would be:

| Credit Number | Currency | Credit | Pass/Fail |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | USD | 0 | Fail |
| ABC123 | EUR | 2,000,000 | Fail |
| ABC123 | GBP | 3,000,000 | Fail |
| OPQ654 | USD | 3,500,000 | Fail |
| OPQ654 | EUR | 4,000,000 | Fail |
| OPQ654 | GBP | 5,000,000 | Fail |
| XYZ555 | USD | 10,000,000 | Fail |
| XYZ555 | EUR | 11,000,000 | Fail |
| XYZ555 | GBP | 13,000,000 | Fail |
| JKL900 | USD | 20,000,000 | Pass |
| JKL900 | EUR | 19,000,000 | Pass |
| JKL | GBP | 16,000,000 | Pass |

Any thoughts how I could best add a column with output based on comparisons at Credit Number level in Power Query? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in powerquery

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Credit Number"}, {{"data", each 
    let #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(_, List.Distinct(_[Currency]), "Currency", "Credit", List.Sum),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Pivoted Column", "Custom", each if ([USD]=null or [USD]=0) then "Fail" else if [USD]>[EUR] then "Pass" else if [USD]<[EUR] then "Fail" else "Pass")
    in #"Added Custom"[Custom]{0}  }}),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Source, {"Credit Number"}, #"Grouped Rows", {"Credit Number"}, "xx", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expand" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "xx", {"data"}, {"Pass/Fail"})
in #"Expand"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt reply, this looks interesting! Can you explain the steps on what this approach is all about? Is it creating an extra table and then merging it? Also I am not sourcing from an Excel Workbook but perform this check directly in Power BI i.e. an existing query; just wondering which part of your example I need to modify to fit my setup, after seeing a few "data" and "xx" in your code? Appreciated, thanks!

Comment: it is creating a a group that becomes a table, and merging.  Click each step individually and you can see what it doing

Comment: I saw you updated the query recently, so I took it and tried to fit it into my environment. Most of the values in the newly created/merged column are Errors though, and only few are "Fail" and no "Pass". The error message is always something like: "The field `USD` of the record wasn't found". Also sometimes I get "We cannot convert the value null to type Logical"